# dotnet publish with an Apache server

Tags: apache, centos, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core application ready to deploy. I've already tested this application on my Linux (CentOS) server with the command:

> dotnet run

and everything is running smothly. Now I want to publish this web application on my Apache server. So far I've runned the command

> dotnet publish

which created a folder named **netcoreapp1.0**. I've moved that folder to the var/www/mywebsite folder and created the respective sites-enabled and sites-avaliable conf files. The problem is I cannot access application at all.

With this, I would like to know if there is anyone out there that had published a .NET Core application into an Apache server in order to give some tutorial on how they did it.

Comment: Don't force tags into question title

Comment: Dunno about Apache, but basically you run .NET Core behind an webserver and use it only as reverse proxy (that's what IIS also does with .NET Core Apps). Start the application normally and set your server to redirect traffic to your app

Comment: @Tseng yeap. Apparently thats the way to go! Thank you :)

Comment: Feel free to post your steps you used to achieve it as an answer and mark it as accepted so others looking on SO know how to do it exactly

Comment: Also please don't put tags into question title (I just had to edit 7 of your recent questions removing the tags from title...) , see FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging. And no "Thanks" at the end of the posts, it's not a forum, it's a Q/A site